# How to get SSLSocketFactorry using SSL certificate with Volley

Tags: android, ssl, android-volley

I'm trying to upload image to the server with SSL using the Volley. I prepare method to get SSLSocketFactory, and getting SSLSocketFactory using SSL certificate in its methods. I'm getting RequestQueue from this SSLSocketFactory instance in different method.

But CertificateException error "inStream is empty" occurs at the point where it was shown by the // Error.

The cause seems to be the contents of R.raw.sslcrt. The contents of R.raw.sslcrt is as follows.

```
—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–
MIID1TCCAr2gAwIBAgID
// omission
0wVaydWTQBUbHq3tw==
—–END CERTIFICATE—–
—–BEGIN CERTIFICATE—–
MIIDfTCCAuagAwIBAgID
// omission
84dJzjA1BOoa+Y7mHyhD
—–END CERTIFICATE—–
```

I don't know it should be the contents of R.raw.sslcrt to any content. CRT file or CSR file or otherwise? Currently I have used the CRT file of the server without edit.

What should I do?

```
private static SSLSocketFactory
getSSLSocketFactory(Context context)
        throws CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        KeyStoreException,
        KeyManagementException,
        IOException{

    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sslcrt);

    // Error
    Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(inputStream);

    String keyType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", certificate);
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that:
PEM is Base64 encoded DER certificate

I think problem here may be that you want to feed `generateCertificate` method with PEM formatted certificate (and I thinks it only accepts DER, however I wasn't able to find it in docementation). Try to convert it to DER (you can do it in code, or using openssl). You can even store whole certificate as String in your application.

As soon as you have PEM string you can try this:

```
public X509Certificate parseCertificate(String certificate) throws CertificateException {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(certificate.replaceAll("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "").replaceAll("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", ""));
    return (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
}
```

Another option to resolve your problem is to create BKS keystore using openssl and BouncyCastle library, add certificates to it and store if in raw folder.

You can also try to use BouncyCastle PemParser: http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMParser.html